# Use map function to validate each input and create border around the input which is invalid or empty on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, map-function

i am working on a form which has multiple steps so in each step when i click next it validate the current active step page with map function.
i want to achieve Use map function to validate each input and create border around the input which is invalid or empty on button click
why i am doing this is that i don't want to get the values of input one by one and apply conditions on them.

new to JS and jQuery. Any help will be appreciated

**what i tried so far but no result only error**

```js
var getstep1 = $("#step1 :input").map(function(getinput)
{   
    if($(getinput).val() == '')
    {
        return $(this).css('width', '10px');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".next").click(function() {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
        });
    }
      // return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it that complicated. You can use a form validator plugin - `Validator.js`, you can download it [here](https://github.com/yairEO/validator/archive/master.zip)

1. Load the validator.js script into the document.
2. Load the multifield.js if you’d like to validate a form field containing multiple inputs.
3. Disable the native HTML5 data validation on your form.

...

4. Apply validators to the form fields using the following attributes:

- required: is required?
- pattern: ‘numeric’, ‘alphanumeric’, ‘url’, ‘phone’, ’email’, or custom regex.
- data-validate-words: Specify the minimum amount of words for this field.
- data-validate-length: Specify the length allowed for the field (after trim). For example: [3,10] means that the field can only have 3 or 10 characters.
- data-validate-length-range: Specify the minimum and/or maximum number of chars in the field (after trim).
- data-validate-linked: Specify the field which the current field’s value (the attribute is set on) should be compared to.
- data-validate-minmax: Specify the minimum and/or maximum value.

  Name

  Occupation

  Email

  Confirm Email address

  Number

5. Initialize the form validator on the form element and done.

   var validator = new FormValidator({
   // options here
   });
6. Validate the form on submit (OPTIONAL).

   document.forms.onsubmit = function(e){
   var submit = true,
   validatorResult = validator.checkAll(this);
   console.log(validatorResult);
   return !!validatorResult.valid;
   };
7. Default settings to config the form validator.

   var validator = new FormValidator({
   // shows alert tooltip
   alerts : true,
   // custom trigger events
   // e.g. ['blur', 'input', 'change']
   events : false,
   // predefined validators
   regex : {
   url          : /^(https?://)?([\w\d-_]+.+[A-Za-z]{2,})+/?/,
   phone        : /^+?([0-9]|[-|' '])+$/i,
   numeric      : /^[0-9]+$/i,
   alphanumeric : /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i,
   email        : {
   illegalChars : /[()<>,;:\/"[]]/,
   filter       : /^.+@.+..{2,6}$/ // exmaple email "steve@s-i.photo"
   }
   },
   // default CSS classes
   classes : {
   item  : 'field',
   alert : 'alert',
   bad   : 'bad'
   }
   });
8. Default error messages.

   texts : {
   invalid         : 'inupt is not as expected',
   short           : 'input is too short',
   long            : 'input is too long',
   checked         : 'must be checked',
   empty           : 'please put something here',
   select          : 'Please select an option',
   number_min      : 'too low',
   number_max      : 'too high',
   url             : 'invalid URL',
   number          : 'not a number',
   email           : 'email address is invalid',
   email_repeat    : 'emails do not match',
   date            : 'invalid date',
   time            : 'invalid time',
   password_repeat : 'passwords do not match',
   no_match        : 'no match',
   complete        : 'input is not complete'
   },

The form will look like this:
[image: Form validation sample screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to use any type of plugin